# How I can load a sys.ini language file

Tags: joomla-3.x, language, system-plugin

I need in an own system plugin some language values from a **sys.ini** language file.

I could only found this way to load the normal .ini file:

```
$language = JFactory::getLanguage();
$language->load('com_yourcomponentname', JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR);
```

Comment: Okay i have get it:
$language->load('com_yourcomponentname.sys', JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR);